# MobX: How to bind a @computed function (like with @action.bound)?

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

I try to decorate this function in my store with `@computed`:

```
  public isSelected = () => {
    return this.session.selection === this;
  };
```

Something like e.g.:

```
  @computed
  get isSelected() {
    return this.selection === this;
  };
```

But this way `this` is not bound to my object.
Is there something like `@computed.bound`?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Yes, can you post your entire store, or at least the relevant portions of your store?